# replace string between first two occurrence of '&' chars

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

How can I replace string between first `&` and next `&` only:

```
public class Test02 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String xyz = "&axy=asdsd&ram=2 gb4 gb&asd=sdsd&";

    String x =  xyz.replaceAll("&ram=.*&", "&ram=8 gb&");

    System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

my input -  `&axy=asdsd&ram=2 gb4 gb&asd=sdsd&`
my output - `&axy=asdsd&ram=8 gb&`

but  I want- `&axy=asdsd&ram=8 gb&asd=sdsd&`

only want to change middle part.

I am making a search filter. If any API for building query exists I would love to know.

Comment: [Watch Out for The Greediness!](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) Try [.*?](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) instead `.*`

Comment: Use [`String x =  xyz.replaceFirst("&ram=[^&]*&", "&ram=8 gb&");`](http://ideone.com/B7Fzia). Leverage `replaceFirst` to only perform one S&R operation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks bobble,

this worked... '.*?' instead of '.*' ..

public class Test02 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String xyz = "&axy=asdsd&ram=2 gb4 gb&asd=sdsd&";

    String x =  xyz.replaceAll("(&ram=.*?)&", "&ram=8 gb&");

    System.out.println(x);
}
```

}

now out put-- &axy=asdsd&ram=8 gb&asd=sdsd&

Comment: `replaceAll` will match and replace more than you need in other strings with more `&` in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` method on your String to break it into its tokens with a given delimiter. Then just replace whatever index you want with the new desired value.

Something like this (not tested)

```
String text = "A&B&C";
String delim = "&";
String[] elements = text.split(delim);
elements[0]= "D";
String result = "";
for (String token : elements) {
    result += token + delim;
}
System.out.println(result.substring(0, result.length() - delim.length())); // "D&B&C"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String xyz = "&axy=asdsd&ram=2 gb4 gb&asd=sdsd&";
    int firstAndPosition =xyz.indexOf('&',1);
    int secondAndPosition =xyz.indexOf('&',firstAndPosition+1);
    String stringToReplace = xyz.substring(firstAndPosition, secondAndPosition +1);

    //The do your stuff
    String x =  xyz.replaceAll(stringToReplace, "&ram=8 gb&");
    System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a negated character class `[^&]` matching any character but a `&` with a `*` quantifier (zero or more occurrences) and leverage `String#replaceFirst()` method to only perform one replacement:

```
String xyz = "&axy=asdsd&ram=2 gb4 gb&asd=sdsd&";
String x =  xyz.replaceFirst("&ram=[^&]*&", "&ram=8 gb&");
System.out.println(x);
// => &axy=asdsd&ram=8 gb&asd=sdsd&
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/B7Fzia)